# Regex a date-like string

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract a substring `022014-101` from a string `str1`:

```
str1 = <C:\User\Test\xyz\022014-101\more\stuff\022014\1>
             # I dont need the 2nd 022014, only the first occuring one 022014-101
```

I usually use `split("\\")` and split the string after `\` to get the `[-5]`'th item but that is bad in case I have more subfolders... As you can see the first 6 digits of `022014-101` are representing a date plus some characters (-101 in this case). I think I should use regex, but how can I match 6 digits and get everything until a `\` occurs. I dont have much experience with regex, anyone knows the solution? Thanks.

Comment: +1 for the fact that you actually specified *what you want* to match unlike most regex questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this: `(?<=\\)[\d]{6}[^\\]*`

**Example:** http://regex101.com/r/qQ0tR3

**Explanation:**

```
(?<=\\)         # Lookbehind for a \ (escaped \\)
[\d]{6}         # Followed by 6 digits
[^\\]*          # Followed by 0+ characters other than a \ (escaped \\)
```

This will ensure your 6 digit date comes directly after a `\` and include everything up until the next `\`.

Answer (score 1):

How about: `(\d{6}.*?)\\`, the first match group would give you what you want. See http://regex101.com/r/aP3bJ7

Answer (score 0):

**Try this** (the first match will always be what you need) :

```
\\([\d\-]+)\\
```

**Demo :**

http://regex101.com/r/pI0yP7

**Explanation :**

```
"\\([\d-]+)\\"

\\ matches the character \ literally
        1st Capturing group ([\d-]+)
        [\d-]+ match a single character present in the list below
        Quantifier: Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
        \d match a digit [0-9]
        - the literal character -
\\ matches the character \ literally
```