# Regex error in python

Tags: python

I have a string that looks like a path from which I am trying to extract `020414_001` with a regular expression I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21913362/regex-a-date-like-string).

```
str1 = "Test 123 <C:\User\Test\xyz\022014-101\more\stuff\022014\1> Text"
```

Actually I am retrieving the string from a text file so I dont have to escape it, but for testing purpose I used this string instead:

```
str1 = <C:\\User\\Test\\xyz\\022014-101\\more\\stuff\\022014\\1>
```

Here is the code I tried to match the first occuring `022014-101`:

```
import re
p = re.compile('(?<=\\)[\d]{6}[^\\]*')
m = p.match(str1)
print m.group(0)   #Line 6
```

It gave me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test12.py", line 6, in <module>
    print m.group(0)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

How can I get the desired output `020414_001` ?

EDIT:

That did it:

```
import re
m = re.search(r'(?<=\\)[\d]{6}[^\\]*', str1)
print m.group(0)
```

Comment: `re.match` matches from the start of the string, try with `re.search` instead.

Comment: Also, if you use raw strings ```r'C:\User\Test\...'``` you don't need the escape characters.

Comment: You will also need to make the string you give to `re.compile` a raw string. Otherwise the double backslash will be escaped to a single backslash by python.

Comment: Thanks Zhehao Mao, I manged it.